# Youtube and MP3 extraction on debian Wheezy

Tags: shell-script, debian, youtube

Are there any alternatives to youtube-dl? I simply want to fetch a Youtube URL, extract it, convert it to MP3, download it, and play it. I would like to use `youtube-dl` but it doesn't work properly under debian Wheezy. I want to do this within a web browser. For example, the `elinks` or `w3m` console web browsers.

Comment: It just sinply doesn't work. The system i'm using is a Zipit Z2 (palmtop computer). And I have Debian Wheezy installed on it. And, AFAIK, youtube-dl isn't supported on it. I get a slew of Python errors. Which, i've tried to solve, but have been unsuccessful in doing so.

Comment: I used to have my own youtube downloader, written in perl (and it was working on my 2008 nokia n810), but recent changes to youtube (a month or so ago) broke it. If I ever come around to fix it, I'll put it somewhere and post a link here. Let's hope your question is not deleted by the offtopic brigade until then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an extended comment.

youtube-dl has a lot of dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt install youtube-dl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg libavdevice57 libdc1394-22 libdouble-conversion1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5
  libqt5network5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5svg5 libqt5webchannel5
  libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsndio6.1 libuchardet0 libxcb-xinerama0 mpv phantomjs python3-pyxattr
  qt5-gtk-platformtheme qttranslations5-l10n rtmpdump
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg-doc libportaudio2 qt5-image-formats-plugins qtwayland5 qt5-qmltooling-plugins sndiod python3-pyxattr-dbg
  python-pyxattr-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg libavdevice57 libdc1394-22 libdouble-conversion1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5
  libqt5network5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5svg5 libqt5webchannel5
  libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsndio6.1 libuchardet0 libxcb-xinerama0 mpv phantomjs python3-pyxattr
  qt5-gtk-platformtheme qttranslations5-l10n rtmpdump youtube-dl
0 upgraded, 30 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 114 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

That's quite a few libraries that need to be compiled for the architecture of that little device.

Comment: Thank you for that. But, like I said `youtube-dl` isn't available for Debian "Wheezy".

Comment: ..Which is why i'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VLC you can use cvlc (improvement can be made):

```
cvlc -vvv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAAAA --sout '#es{access_audio=file,mux_audio=ts,url_audio=audio-%c.%m}'
```

Output file will be in 2 parts, the audio is the stream-0-mp4a.

Comment: Don't have VLC on the Zipit. :/ It would be way too slow, anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You could record the audio externally, heaphone out into line-in, save as .wav, and convert to .mp3 from there.